Better approach of DBMS.SUBSTR CLOB_Column
Recently I'm working in a BE Application with Node.js, TypeScript and oracle-sql server.
There is a DB table, TableA which contains columns: ID (NUMBER) & App_Log_File (CLOB).
Column App_Log_File contains a entire log_file according to db-structure/business-logic. According to my observation, some rows are containing 3-4.5MB text(log) files, around 40K-60K Lines in that log files.
As, Column App_Log_File datatype is COLB. So, I used function DBMS_LOB.substr(clob_colm_name, maxCharacterLength, startIndex) to fetch the App_Log_File column data.
But, Oracle SQL Server allowing only 4000 characters to fetch from CLOB Data.
So, I created SQL schema as follows:
interface LogFileReqModel {
    rowId: number,
    logfilelength: number
}

function getLogFilesSchema(query: LogFileReqModel): string {
    const maxCharacterLength: number = 4000;
    const loopLength: number = Number(((query.logfilelength||0)/maxCharacterLength).toFixed(0));

    let fetchLogQuery: string = ''
    for(let i=0; i<(loopLength + 1); i++) {
        fetchLogQuery += (fetchLogQuery ? ',\n' : '') + `\t\tDBMS_LOB.substr(App_Log_File, ${maxCharacterLength}, ${maxCharacterLength*i + 1}) AS log_file_${i}`;
    }

    let sqlSchema: string = `
        SELECT 
        -- ID,
        ${query.logfilelength > 0 ? fetchLogQuery : `'' AS log_file_0`}
        FROM TableA
        WHERE ID = ${query.rowId}`;

    return sqlSchema;
}

const logFileSqlSchema: string = getLogFilesSchema({ rowId: 12, logfilelength: 3589833 });
console.log('sqlSchema: ', logFileSqlSchema);

Which basically creating dynamic log_file columns query depend on Log File Length as follows:
SELECT 
    -- ID,
    DBMS_LOB.substr(App_Log_File, 4000, 1) AS log_file_0,
    DBMS_LOB.substr(App_Log_File, 4000, 4001) AS log_file_1,
    DBMS_LOB.substr(App_Log_File, 4000, 8001) AS log_file_2,
    DBMS_LOB.substr(App_Log_File, 4000, 12001) AS log_file_3,
    DBMS_LOB.substr(App_Log_File, 4000, 16001) AS log_file_4,
    ... ... ...
    ... ... ...
    DBMS_LOB.substr(App_Log_File, 4000, 3580001) AS log_file_895,
    DBMS_LOB.substr(App_Log_File, 4000, 3584001) AS log_file_896,
    DBMS_LOB.substr(App_Log_File, 4000, 3588001) AS log_file_897
FROM TableA
WHERE ID = 12

Typescript Demo Query

Is there other way to improve the SQL schema ? 
If yes please pass me SQL query suggestion, I'll upgrade accordingly.

Why are you trying to read the CLOB in chunks? If you want to return the entire CLOB then SELECT app_log_file FROM TableA WHERE id = 12.

Agree with MT0 - get rid of the DBMS_LOB.substr. You may want to set oracledb.fetchAsString like the docs suggest.


Don't include variables in query by using string concatenation (or template strings). Use a bind variable.
If you want to return the contents of a CLOB column then just read the CLOB column. (You do not need to split it up into VARCHAR2-sized chunks.)

Your code could be simplified to:
const logFileSqlSchema: string = "SELECT App_Log_File FROM TableA WHERE ID = ?";
console.log('sqlSchema: ', logFileSqlSchema);

Then when you want to run the query bind your id value to the anonymous bind variable ? and then stream the CLOB when you read the result-set.

Yes you are absolutely right. I need to implement Data Mapper patterns javascript library like: TypeORM. Thanks for suggestion @MTO
